# Bash has problems with cmdline nft cmd vs script

Tags: bash, nftables

linux mint. *uname -r* yields **5.15.0-56**. *dpkg-query -l bash* yields **5.1.6ubuntu1**.
My script shows this problematic output
when *bash -x script* invoked:

```
attrib =' '\''{type nat hook prerouting  priority mangle+10;}'\'' '
```

But from the commandline:

```
sudo nft create chain inet firewalld mangle_PREROUTING '{ type nat hook prerouting priority mangle + 10 ;}'
```

It works fine.
This script replicates the fedora nft tree.

```
 x=$(sudo nft -a list tables)   
 if [[ $x != '' ]]; then  
     sudo nft flush table inet firewalld  
      sudo nft delete table inet firewalld  
 fi  
 sudo nft create table inet firewalld  
 for stage in mangle net filter;do  
     for step in _PREROUTING _OUTPUT _INPUT _IN_workstation; do
      meat=${step/_/}   
       priority=${stage/_/}   
       a=${step/_[a-zA-Z]+/_}   
       b=${stage/_[a-zA-Z]+/_}   
       if [[ $stage =="__"]]; then   
            type="nat"   
       else
            type="filter"   
       fi.   
       hook=${meat,,}   #translate to all lowercase.  
       attrib=" '{ type "$type" hook "$hook" priority "$priority"+10;}'"   

      
    if[[ $a$b == "__" ]]; then   
        cmd=" insert rule inet firewalld $stage$step" ;   
         sudo nft $cmd  
     else  
         cmd=" create chain inet firewalld $stage$step $attrib";   
        sudo nft $cmd  
    fi  
     done  
  done
```

Comment: tagged `bash` but that isn't valid bash script with all those random `.` all over the place

Comment: If it is meant to be a bash script, use https://www.shellcheck.net/ and implement the recommandations. Due to quoting issues, you will need several iterations.

Comment: That's an android/spellcheck/server fault artifact. It was a lot to type in.. but fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the single quotes around the curly braces was the answer. I tried this because I figured the shell script (and sudo) were doing a fork/exec, for nft, with no shell interpretation.

Comment: With single quotes nft will receive a single parameter which is not recognized. Without them, nft parse all parts separately and can build the right syntax tree.