# Bash parameter substitution (baparmsub?) Isnt working

Tags: bash

[ using *bash -cx 'a="_IN_workstation"; b=${a/*[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]/_};echo x.$b.x' does partially work but the lack of parenthesis will skew the match. So this points to the parenthesis processing being the problem but I have seen the work of *GNU autoconf* which suggests something else.
Anybody familiar with bash internals?
]

I am having a problem with feeding values like _PREROUTING _POSTROUTING  to strip out alphabet chars :

```
a=${step/\_+([a-zA-Z]/\_}
[ note: replacing underscore with \x5f does nothing for the script although using sed works via 's/_[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*/_/gp' but that is NOT what i __wanted__]
```

(GNU)[https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html] seems to agree with me, my bash does(5.1) not have *shop +patsub_replacement* available for 5.2.

linux mint version and bash version see *step* variable and [original script in]
([Bash has problems with cmdline nft cmd vs script](https://serverfault.com/questions/1142696/bash-has-problems-with-cmdline-nft-cmd-vs-script/1142770#1142770))

I tried `[:alpha:]` but neither works in script and rarely at the command line.

Comment: Some improvement at command line.Cite a place in the bash man page for escaping underscores?

Comment: I can't understand what you want to get in `a`? Just two underscores?

Comment: BTW, did you forget to put closing parenthesis? This `${step//_+([a-zA-Z])/_}` should work.

Comment: Alexey, yes two underscores mean something isn't an nft rule WITHOUT a hook or priority. See the link above.

Comment: Yes, in a non-interactive shell script it doesn't. Run the shell script with the "-x' option and  tell me about the results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `shopt -s extglob` which is usually `on` for interactive shell, but `off` in scripts.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

step=_SOME_under_SCORES
a=${step//_+([a-zA-Z])/_}

echo "[$step]=>[$a]"
```

```
$ ./check.sh
[_SOME_under_SCORES]=>[___]
```

See `man bash` section **Pattern Matching**:

> If the **extglob**  shell  option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized […]

Comment: Sorry. Your solution doesnt work.Your assertion is correct but why is it not spelled out? Using bash -c "" have the extglob turned off. The second problem is spelled out at the new top of article I added 12hrs ago roughly. Those parenthesis I suspect are the problem.

Comment: I have exhilarated via bt logs of all of my trials.

Answer (score 0):

The machine gods ,apparently, have had enough time laughing at me. Alexey Ten did contribute substantially to the answer I believe.

y= ${step//_[[:alpha:]]+([[:alpha:]])/_}